# Opencart tags url seo friendly?

Tags: php, url, seo, opencart

I want to change the url of tags 
`www.store.com/index.php?route=product/search&tag=Mercury`
to 
`www.store.com/tag/Mercury`

I tried to change the code of `catalog/controller/common/seo_url.php`
replacing the code with

```
     } elseif ($data['route'] == 'product/search' && $key == 'tag') {

                        $url .= '/tag/' . $value;

                        unset($data[$key]);

                    } elseif ($key == 'path') {
```

but to no avail,

of course `opencart` seo url friendly is on and working fine for the other things like products and categories,

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

in your .htaccess file add this:

```
RewriteRule ^tag/([^?]*)? /search?tag=$1 [L,QSA]
```

before:

```
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then in your product.tpl
change those:

```
<a href="<?php echo $tags[$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $tags[$i]['tag']; ?></a>
```

to:

```
<a href="<?php echo 'tag/'.$tags[$i]['tag']; ?>"><?php echo $tags[$i]['tag']; ?></a>
```

This way you don't have to manipulate core files.

Hope that helps.

//EDIT

Here is the part in your product.tpl

```
<?php if ($tags) { ?>
  <p><?php echo $text_tags; ?>
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($tags); $i++) { ?>
    <?php if ($i < (count($tags) - 1)) { ?>
    <!-- <a href="<?php echo $tags[$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $tags[$i]['tag']; ?></a> -->
    <a href="<?php echo 'tag/'.$tags[$i]['tag']; ?>"><?php echo $tags[$i]['tag']; ?></a>,
    <?php } else { ?>
    <!-- <a href="<?php echo $tags[$i]['href']; ?>"><?php echo $tags[$i]['tag']; ?></a> -->
    <a href="<?php echo '/tag/'.$tags[$i]['tag']; ?>"><?php echo $tags[$i]['tag']; ?></a>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
  </p>
  <?php } ?>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteRule ^tag/([^?]*)? index.php?route=product/search&tag=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```